# Tokenizing based on certain pattern with Python

Tags: python, nltk, python-re

I have to tokenize certain patterns from sentences that have Sentences like `abc ABC - - 12 V` and `ab abc 1,2W`. Here both `12 V` and `1,2W` are values with units. So I want to tokenize as `abc`,`ABC` and `12 V`. For the other case:  `ab` , `abc` , `1,2W`. 
How can I do that ? 
Well nltk word_tokenizer is an option but I can not insert any pattern, or can I ?
`word_tokenize(test_word)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is predictable, in the sense that you know which characters appear between your tokens (in this case I see a space and a hyphen), you can use a regex to extract what you want:

```
import re

def is_float(s):
    return re.match(r'^-?\d+(?:\.|,\d+)?$', s) 

def extract_tokens(phrase, noise="-"):
    phrase_list = re.split("\s+", re.sub(noise, " ", phrase).strip())
    phrase_tokenized = []
    i, n = 0, len(phrase_list)
    while i < n:
        phrase_tokenized.append(phrase_list[i])
        if phrase_list[i].isdigit() or is_float(phrase_list[i]) and i < n-1:
            phrase_tokenized[-1] += " " + phrase_list[i+1]
            i += 1
        i += 1
    return phrase_tokenized
```

Sample test:

```
>>> extract_tokens("abc ABC - - 12 V")
['abc', 'ABC', '12 V']
>>> extract_tokens("ab abc 1,2W")
['ab', 'abc', '1,2W']
```

And to "insert a pattern" all you need to do is update the `noise` parameter according to what you want.

Comment: I am getting now `IndexError: list index out of range` is i have more data. The error is here `phrase_tokenized[-1] += " " + phrase_list[i+1]`

Comment: if the list of list is bigger then 25  or if i am slicing the data from somewhere

Comment: Show me the problematic input